# Moving extension from Connect to Marketplace problem

Tags: magento-connect, marketplace

Magento announced they will close Magento Connect site just 30 days before closure. Everything would be OK if they would provide a fast way to move extension from Connect to Marketplace, but this is not a case.

It took almost 1 week to get approved business review. Now I need to submit extension to pass technical review. But when I try to upload extension it shows this error:

```
You have already created the "company/module_name" extension. Use the edit form for adding new versions.
```

I don't have any existing extension inside, only the one with business review status. I contacted their support, I even contacted their partnership program and was ready to pay almost $5000 for their partnership program to get priority support, but they simply ignored my message and after 1 week I still don't have any reply from them. I get main revenue from Google serp (1st position) but if they close Connect site before they move my extension to Marketplace I will lose this position and most of the revenue.

Do anybody face the same problem about "You have already created the..." error? I am lost here, I can not get their support but they will close the site in 4 days. Not very professional from them.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem from their side, I finally received answer: `There was a slight issue on the backend of developer portal that has been corrected`

Now I could upload the extension. Not very professional from Magento team to announce closure of Connect site just 30 days before and they can not handle smooth transfer of extensions to Marketplace in that time.